# RegEx to get start and end times

Tags: regex

I want to extract '12:00 PM' and '9:00 PM' from:

```
'Time: 12:00 PM to 9:00 PM'
```

I'm trying to get them as separate items, so I think two regex expressions are in order. How do I solve this problem?

I tried [this](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/regex-match-everything-after-this-word/20764) to grab everything after 'to' but it isn't working for some reason.

Comment: Hi, for help and guidance on posting these are useful [mcve] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/fYJITF/1) might help you to get those times separately:

```
[0-9:]+\sPM|AM
```

[image]

This RegEx creates two groups using `()` where you can get those times easier using `$1` and `$2`

If you may want an exact match, you may try [this](https://regex101.com/r/6B5QiO/2):

```
^Time: ([0-9:AMP\s]+)\sto ([0-9:AMP\s]+)
```

[image]

Comment: This is good, but I need one expression to grab the first date, and another one to grab the second